# How to animate a Pico.css accordion

Tags: css

I'm using [Pico.css](https://picocss.com/) and can't seem to figure out how to animate the height of its [Accordion](https://picocss.com/docs/accordions.html).

I tried with the addition in the `<style>` tags, but that doesn't seem to do anything:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>XYZ</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@picocss/pico@1.5.11/css/pico.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- I tried the following -->
    <style>
        details { transition: all 0.3s !important; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="container">
        <section>
            <h2>Test</h2>
            <details>
                <summary>Accordion</summary>
                <p>Hi there</p>
                <p>Hi there</p>
                <p>Hi there</p>
                <p>Hi there</p>
                <p>Hi there</p>
                <p>Hi there</p>
                <p>Hi there</p>
            </details>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it will be better to include more code details for pass the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/helphttps://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). and for clarification i didn't downvoted the q . so make the req changes as soon as possible .

Answer (score 1):

For a CSS-only solution, you can animate the opening somewhat but the closing would not be doable:

```css
.outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  overflow: hidden;
}

[open] .outer {
  animation: show var(--transition);
}

@keyframes show {
  from {
    grid-template-rows: 0fr;
  }
}

.inner {
  min-height: 0;
}

details summary {
  transition-property: margin-bottom, color !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@picocss/pico@1/css/pico.min.css">

<main class="container">
  <section>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <details>
      <summary>Accordion 1</summary>
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
          <p>Hi there</p>
          <p>Hi there</p>
          <p>Hi there</p>
          <p>Hi there</p>
          <p>Hi there</p>
          <p>Hi there</p>
          <p>Hi there</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </details>
  </section>
</main>
```

With JavaScript, one can prevent the default `<summary>` click from closing the `<details>`, allowing one to play a CSS transition (or similar) before the `<details>` is closed:

```js
document
  .querySelector('details')
  .addEventListener('toggle', ({ target }) => {
    // When toggled open:
    if (target.open) {
      // Add class to play CSS transition.
      target.classList.add('open');
    }
  });
  
document
  .querySelector('summary')
  .addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const details = event.target.closest('details');
    // If the details this summary is controlling is open:
    if (details.open) {
      // Stop the browser from closing it on summary click.
      event.preventDefault();

      // Wait for the transition to end before closing the detail.
      details
        .querySelector('.outer')
        .addEventListener(
          'transitionend',
          () => {
            details.open = false;
          },
          { once: true }
        );
 
      // Remove the open class to play CSS transition.
      details.classList.remove('open');
    }
  });
```

```css
.outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: grid-template-rows var(--transition);
}

.open > .outer {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.inner {
  min-height: 0;
}

details summary {
  transition-property: margin-bottom, color !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@picocss/pico@1/css/pico.min.css">

<main class="container">
  <section>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <details>
      <summary>Accordion 1</summary>
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
          <p>Hi there</p>
          <p>Hi there</p>
          <p>Hi there</p>
          <p>Hi there</p>
          <p>Hi there</p>
          <p>Hi there</p>
          <p>Hi there</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </details>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is way more complicated than I expected.